# ns: [code omitted because of length]

Tags: cygwin, windows-xp, ns2

I have installed [NS2](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/) on Windows XP using Cygwin. There was no error during installation (I used [this tutorial](http://csie.nqu.edu.tw/smallko/ns2_old/setup_en.htm)), but I'm not able to use NS because of this error below. After entering `./ns.exe` :

```
ns: [code omitted because of length] : invalid command name "Agent/TCP/Newreno/AP" while executing "Agent/TCP/Newreno/AP set n_factor_ 4"
```

When I configured the output is:

```
$ ./configure
No .configure file found in current directory
Continuing with default options...
checking build system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking host system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking target system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output... a.exe
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for main in -lXbsd... no
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking for gethostbyname in -lnsl... no
checking for dcgettext in -lintl... yes
checking for getnodebyname in -ldnet_stub... no
checking that g++ can handle -O2... no
checking if C++ libraries work without any namespace... no
checking if C++ libraries work with namespace std... yes
checking if STL works without any namespace... no
checking if STL works with namespace std... yes
checking should use STL... yes
checking for tcl.h... -I../include
checking for libtcl8.4... -L../lib -ltcl8.4
checking for init.tcl... ../lib/tcl8.4
checking for tclsh8.4.5... no
checking for tclsh8.4... no
checking for tclsh... ../tcl8.4.5/unix/tclsh
checking for tk.h... -I../include
checking for libtk8.4... -L../lib -ltk8.4
checking for tk.tcl... ../lib/tk8.4
checking for otcl.h... -I../otcl-1.9
checking for libotcl1.9... -L../otcl-1.9 -lotcl
checking for tclcl.h... -I../tclcl-1.16
checking for libtclcl... -L../tclcl-1.16 -ltclcl
checking for tcl2c++... ../tclcl-1.16
checking for X11 header files
checking for X11 library archive
checking for XOpenDisplay in -lX11... no
checking for libXext.a
warning: compiling without -lXext
checking for libtcldbg... -L/home/rihanna/ns-allinone-naderi-modified/ns-2.28/..
/tcl-debug-2.0 -ltcldbg
checking dmalloc... not requested with --with-dmalloc
checking for perl... /usr/bin
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes
checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking fenv.h usability... no
checking fenv.h presence... no
checking for fenv.h... no
checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking time.h usability... yes
checking time.h presence... yes
checking for time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking net/ethernet.h usability... no
checking net/ethernet.h presence... no
checking for net/ethernet.h... no
checking for main in -lm... yes
checking for bcopy... yes
checking for bzero... yes
checking for fesetprecision... no
checking for feenableexcept... no
checking for getrusage... yes
checking for sbrk... yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking return type of random... int
checking for int8_t... yes
checking for int16_t... yes
checking for int32_t... yes
checking for u_int8_t... yes
checking for u_int16_t... yes
checking for u_int32_t... yes
checking for u_char... yes
checking for u_int... yes
checking for strtoq... no
checking for strtoll... yes
checking for long... yes
checking size of long... 4
checking for __int64_t... no
checking for long long... yes
checking for int64_t... yes
checking which kind of 64-bit int to use... int64_t
checking for struct ether_header... not found
checking for struct ether_addr... not found
checking for addr2ascii... no
checking for Linux compliant tcphdr... not found
checking for BSD compliant tcphdr... found
checking for socklen_t... yes
checking for main in -lpcap... no
checking to make nse... no
Explicitly disabling static compilation
no dynamic load lib
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating tcl/lib/ns-autoconf.tcl
config.status: creating indep-utils/webtrace-conv/ucb/Makefile
config.status: creating indep-utils/webtrace-conv/dec/Makefile
config.status: creating indep-utils/webtrace-conv/nlanr/Makefile
config.status: creating indep-utils/webtrace-conv/epa/Makefile
config.status: creating indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest/Makefile
config.status: creating autoconf.h
config.status: autoconf.h is unchanged
```

The next step is `make clean`

```
$ make clean
rm -f ns nse nsx ns.dyn  tools/random.o tools/rng.o tools/ranvar.o common/misc.o
 common/timer-handler.o common/scheduler.o common/object.o common/packet.o commo
n/ip.o routing/route.o common/connector.o common/ttl.o trace/trace.o trace/trace
-ip.o classifier/classifier.o classifier/classifier-addr.o classifier/classifier
-hash.o classifier/classifier-virtual.o classifier/classifier-mcast.o classifier
/classifier-bst.o classifier/classifier-mpath.o mcast/replicator.o classifier/cl
assifier-mac.o classifier/classifier-qs.o classifier/classifier-port.o src_rtg/c
lassifier-sr.o src_rtg/sragent.o src_rtg/hdr_src.o adc/ump.o qs/qsagent.o qs/hdr
_qs.o apps/app.o apps/telnet.o tcp/tcplib-telnet.o tools/trafgen.o trace/traffic
trace.o tools/pareto.o tools/expoo.o tools/cbr_traffic.o tools/poisson.o adc/tbf
.o adc/resv.o adc/sa.o tcp/saack.o tools/measuremod.o adc/estimator.o adc/adc.o
adc/ms-adc.o adc/timewindow-est.o adc/acto-adc.o adc/pointsample-est.o adc/salin
k.o adc/actp-adc.o adc/hb-adc.o adc/expavg-est.o adc/param-adc.o adc/null-estima
tor.o adc/adaptive-receiver.o apps/vatrcvr.o adc/consrcvr.o common/agent.o commo
n/message.o apps/udp.o common/session-rtp.o apps/rtp.o tcp/rtcp.o common/ivs.o c
ommon/messpass.o common/tp.o common/tpm.o apps/worm.o tcp/tcp.o tcp/tcp-sink.o t
cp/tcp-reno.o tcp/tcp-newreno.o tcp/tcp-vegas.o tcp/tcp-rbp.o tcp/tcp-full.o tcp
/rq.o baytcp/tcp-full-bay.o baytcp/ftpc.o baytcp/ftps.o tcp/scoreboard.o tcp/sco
reboard-rq.o tcp/tcp-sack1.o tcp/tcp-fack.o tcp/tcp-asym.o tcp/tcp-asym-sink.o t
cp/tcp-fs.o tcp/tcp-asym-fs.o tcp/tcp-qs.o tcp/tcp-int.o tcp/chost.o tcp/tcp-ses
sion.o tcp/nilist.o sctp/sctp.o apps/sctp_app1.o sctp/sctp-timestamp.o sctp/sctp
-hbAfterRto.o sctp/sctp-multipleFastRtx.o sctp/sctp-newreno.o tools/integrator.o
 tools/queue-monitor.o tools/flowmon.o tools/loss-monitor.o queue/queue.o queue/
drop-tail.o adc/simple-intserv-sched.o queue/red.o queue/semantic-packetqueue.o
queue/semantic-red.o tcp/ack-recons.o queue/sfq.o queue/fq.o queue/drr.o queue/s
rr.o queue/cbq.o queue/jobs.o queue/marker.o queue/demarker.o link/hackloss.o qu
eue/errmodel.o queue/fec.o link/delay.o tcp/snoop.o gaf/gaf.o link/dynalink.o ro
uting/rtProtoDV.o common/net-interface.o mcast/ctrMcast.o mcast/mcast_ctrl.o mca
st/srm.o common/sessionhelper.o queue/delaymodel.o mcast/srm-ssm.o mcast/srm-top
o.o apps/mftp.o apps/mftp_snd.o apps/mftp_rcv.o apps/codeword.o routing/alloc-ad
dress.o routing/address.o lib/int.Vec.o lib/int.RVec.o lib/dmalloc_support.o web
cache/http.o webcache/tcp-simple.o webcache/pagepool.o webcache/inval-agent.o we
bcache/tcpapp.o webcache/http-aux.o webcache/mcache.o webcache/webtraf.o webcach
e/webserver.o webcache/logweb.o empweb/empweb.o empweb/empftp.o realaudio/realau
dio.o mac/lanRouter.o classifier/filter.o common/pkt-counter.o common/Decapsulat
or.o common/Encapsulator.o common/encap.o mac/channel.o mac/mac.o mac/ll.o mac/m
ac-802_11.o mac/mac-802_3.o mac/mac-tdma.o mac/smac.o mobile/mip.o mobile/mip-re
g.o mobile/gridkeeper.o mobile/propagation.o mobile/tworayground.o mobile/antenn
a.o mobile/omni-antenna.o mobile/shadowing.o mobile/shadowing-vis.o mobile/dumb-
agent.o common/bi-connector.o common/node.o common/mobilenode.o mac/arp.o mobile
/god.o mobile/dem.o mobile/topography.o mobile/modulation.o queue/priqueue.o que
ue/mypriqueue.o queue/dsr-priqueue.o mac/phy.o mac/wired-phy.o mac/wireless-phy.
o mac/mac-timers.o trace/cmu-trace.o mac/varp.o mac/mac-simple.o dsdv/dsdv.o dsd
v/rtable.o queue/rtqueue.o routing/rttable.o imep/imep.o imep/dest_queue.o imep/
imep_api.o imep/imep_rt.o imep/rxmit_queue.o imep/imep_timers.o imep/imep_util.o
 imep/imep_io.o tora/tora.o tora/tora_api.o tora/tora_dest.o tora/tora_io.o tora
/tora_logs.o tora/tora_neighbor.o dsr/dsragent.o dsr/hdr_sr.o dsr/mobicache.o ds
r/path.o dsr/requesttable.o dsr/routecache.o dsr/add_sr.o dsr/dsr_proto.o dsr/fl
owstruct.o dsr/linkcache.o dsr/simplecache.o dsr/sr_forwarder.o aodv/aodv_logs.o
 aodv/aodv.o aodv/aodv_rtable.o aodv/aodv_rqueue.o common/ns-process.o satellite
/satgeometry.o satellite/sathandoff.o satellite/satlink.o satellite/satnode.o sa
tellite/satposition.o satellite/satroute.o satellite/sattrace.o rap/raplist.o ra
p/rap.o rap/media-app.o rap/utilities.o common/fsm.o tcp/tcp-abs.o diffusion/dif
fusion.o diffusion/diff_rate.o diffusion/diff_prob.o diffusion/diff_sink.o diffu
sion/flooding.o diffusion/omni_mcast.o diffusion/hash_table.o diffusion/routing_
table.o diffusion/iflist.o tcp/tfrc.o tcp/tfrc-sink.o mobile/energy-model.o apps
/ping.o tcp/tcp-rfc793edu.o queue/rio.o queue/semantic-rio.o tcp/tcp-sack-rh.o t
cp/scoreboard-rh.o plm/loss-monitor-plm.o plm/cbr-traffic-PP.o linkstate/hdr-ls.
o mpls/classifier-addr-mpls.o mpls/ldp.o mpls/mpls-module.o routing/rtmodule.o c
lassifier/classifier-hier.o routing/addr-params.o nix/hdr_nv.o nix/classifier-ni
x.o nix/nixnode.o routealgo/rnode.o routealgo/bfs.o routealgo/rbitmap.o routealg
o/rlookup.o routealgo/routealgo.o nix/nixvec.o nix/nixroute.o diffserv/dsred.o d
iffserv/dsredq.o diffserv/dsEdge.o diffserv/dsCore.o diffserv/dsPolicy.o diffser
v/ew.o diffserv/dewp.o queue/red-pd.o queue/pi.o queue/vq.o queue/rem.o queue/gk
.o pushback/rate-limit.o pushback/rate-limit-strategy.o pushback/ident-tree.o pu
shback/agg-spec.o pushback/logging-data-struct.o pushback/rate-estimator.o pushb
ack/pushback-queue.o pushback/pushback.o common/parentnode.o trace/basetrace.o c
ommon/simulator.o asim/asim.o common/scheduler-map.o common/splay-scheduler.o li
nkstate/ls.o linkstate/rtProtoLS.o pgm/classifier-pgm.o pgm/pgm-agent.o pgm/pgm-
sender.o pgm/pgm-receiver.o mcast/rcvbuf.o mcast/classifier-lms.o mcast/lms-agen
t.o mcast/lms-receiver.o mcast/lms-sender.o mac/802_11e/mac-802_11e.o mac/802_11
e/priq.o mac/802_11e/d-tail.o mac/802_11e/mac-timers_802_11e.o queue/delayer.o n
oah/noah.o mac/forwarder.o mympeg/mytraffictrace.o mympeg/mytraffictrace2.o mymp
eg/mytraffictrace3.o mympeg/mytraffictrace4.o mympeg/mytraffictrace5.o mympeg/my
udp.o mympeg/myudpsink.o mympeg/myudpsink2.o mympeg/myudpsink3.o mympeg/myfifo.o
 mympeg/myfifo2.o mympeg/monitor_udpsink.o mympeg/myevalvid.o mympeg/myevalvid_s
ink.o mympeg/myevalvid_sink2.o mympeg/myudpsink1.o mydiffserv/myfifo_etb.o mydif
fserv/myfifo_srtcm.o mydiffserv/myfifo_trtcm.o mflood/mflood.o mflood/mflood-seq
table.o ncs/ncs.o measure/mudp.o measure/mudpsink.o measure/mtcpsink.o evalvid_r
a/vbr_rateadapt.o evalvid_ra/evalvid_ra_udp.o evalvid_ra/evalvid_ra_sink.o wimax
/ofdmphy.o wimax/mac802_16pkt.o wimax/serviceflowqos.o wimax/serviceflow.o wimax
/serviceflowhandler.o wimax/connection.o wimax/connectionmanager.o wimax/peernod
e.o wimax/mac802_16.o wimax/sduclassifier.o wimax/destclassifier.o wimax/mac802_
16timer.o wimax/neighborentry.o wimax/neighbordb.o wimax/scheduling/wimaxschedul
er.o wimax/scheduling/bsscheduler.o wimax/scheduling/ssscheduler.o wimax/schedul
ing/ulsubframetimer.o wimax/scheduling/dlsubframetimer.o wimax/scheduling/burst.
o wimax/scheduling/contentionslot.o wimax/scheduling/contentionrequest.o wimax/s
cheduling/contentiontimer.o wimax/scheduling/dlburst.o wimax/scheduling/ulburst.
o wimax/scheduling/framemap.o wimax/scheduling/phypdu.o wimax/scheduling/profile
.o wimax/scheduling/subframe.o wimax/scheduling/scanningstation.o wimax/scheduli
ng/wimaxctrlagent.o dsshaper/dsshaper.o queue/csfq.o queue/mycsfq.o queue/fred.o
 queue/util.o apps/rtpdata.o apps/voip_traffic.o protoname/protoname.o protoname
/protoname_rtable.o xcp/xcpq.o xcp/xcp.o xcp/xcp-end-sys.o wpan/p802_15_4csmaca.
o wpan/p802_15_4fail.o wpan/p802_15_4hlist.o wpan/p802_15_4mac.o wpan/p802_15_4n
am.o wpan/p802_15_4phy.o wpan/p802_15_4sscs.o wpan/p802_15_4timer.o wpan/p802_15
_4trace.o wpan/p802_15_4transac.o diffusion3/lib/nr/nr.o diffusion3/lib/dr.o dif
fusion3/filters/diffusion/one_phase_pull.o diffusion3/filters/diffusion/two_phas
e_pull.o diffusion3/lib/diffapp.o diffusion3/ns/diffagent.o diffusion3/ns/diffrt
g.o diffusion3/ns/difftimer.o diffusion3/filter_core/filter_core.o diffusion3/fi
lter_core/iolog.o diffusion3/filter_core/iostats.o diffusion3/lib/main/attrs.o d
iffusion3/lib/main/events.o diffusion3/lib/main/iodev.o diffusion3/lib/main/ioho
ok.o diffusion3/lib/main/timers.o diffusion3/lib/main/message.o diffusion3/lib/m
ain/tools.o diffusion3/apps/gear_examples/gear_common.o diffusion3/apps/gear_exa
mples/gear_receiver.o diffusion3/apps/gear_examples/gear_sender.o diffusion3/app
s/rmst_examples/rmst_sink.o diffusion3/apps/rmst_examples/rmst_source.o diffusio
n3/apps/ping/1pp_ping_sender.o diffusion3/apps/ping/1pp_ping_receiver.o diffusio
n3/apps/ping/2pp_ping_sender.o diffusion3/apps/ping/2pp_ping_receiver.o diffusio
n3/apps/ping/ping_common.o diffusion3/apps/ping/push_receiver.o diffusion3/apps/
ping/push_sender.o diffusion3/filters/gear/gear_attr.o diffusion3/filters/gear/g
ear.o diffusion3/filters/gear/gear_tools.o diffusion3/filters/misc/log.o diffusi
on3/filters/misc/srcrt.o diffusion3/filters/misc/tag.o diffusion3/filters/rmst/r
mst.o diffusion3/filters/rmst/rmst_filter.o gen/version.o gen/ns_tcl.o gen/ptype
s.o  common/win32.o emulate/net-ip.o emulate/net.o emulate/tap.o emulate/ether.o
 emulate/internet.o emulate/ping_responder.o emulate/arp.o emulate/icmp.o emulat
e/net-pcap.o emulate/nat.o emulate/iptap.o emulate/tcptap.o emulate/inet.o commo
n/tclAppInit.o gen/* ns.core core core.ns core.nsx core.nse common/ptypes2tcl co
mmon/ptypes2tcl.o
```

At last I entered `make` and there isn't any error.